# laravel 5.7 Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang' not found

Tags: json, laravel, notifications, lang, reset-password

I'm facing this error recently :

```
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang'not found 
{"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Lang' 
    not found at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php:60)
```

I had to change the code form :

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password Notification'))
    ->line(Lang::getFromJson('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
    ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
    ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
```

To :

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject(__('Reset Password Notification'))
    ->line(__('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
    ->action(__('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
    ->line(__('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
```

And it works , but I have to do that after every update.

The file ***vendor\laravel\framework\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang.php***:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @method static mixed trans(string $key, array $replace = [], string $locale = null)
 * @method static string transChoice(string $key, int|array|\Countable $number, array $replace = [], string $locale = null)
 * @method static string getLocale()
 * @method static void setLocale(string $locale)
 * @method static string|array|null get(string $key, array $replace = [], string $locale = null, bool $fallback = true)
 *
 * @see \Illuminate\Translation\Translator
 */
class Lang extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'translator';
    }
}
```

> *Note* :  i'm using JSON files for translations.

Any ideas what causing the error?

Comment: Is there a file at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Lang.php`?

Comment: yes the file exist

Comment: I'd first try blowing away `vendor` and doing a fresh `composer install`. That should prevent permissions issues and give you a clean set of files.

Comment: i can't do that i production mode

Comment: Could you run `resolve('Lang')` in tinker and let us know the output?

Comment: @AMAFsoft Why can't you do it in production mode? `composer install` is a standard part of the deployment process.

Comment: ` Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.4 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> resolve('Lang')
=> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang {#3590} `

Comment: @ceejayoz you said : blowing away vendor , i cant do that

Comment: `composer install` regenerates the `vendor` directory.

Comment: no it doesn't . this is the output : Nothing to install or update

Comment: It would if you deleted the vendor directory.  `vendor` should never contain manually modified code so deleting it and regenerating it with `composer install` should fix any dependency issues as ceejayoz suggested multiple times above.

Comment: @Devon is right

Comment: agreed ,, But the project is online.

Comment: i've lunched a global maintenance and do what you guys suggest and it solved the problem, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like @ceejayoz suggest ,removing vendor folder and running `composer install` Solved the problem

Thank you all for the help!